# Allocating memory without using malloc in C

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

as for a little project, my aim is to add a node at the head of a linked-list and allocate "width" bytes of data for the `struct Node` structure. Normally, this would be simple as malloc accomplishes this task; however, I've been instructed to use a function called `newmalloc`, which essentially does the same thing. The `newmalloc` function returns an integer which is what will be used as the number of bytes to allocate the structure. I have provided my header file which contains the struct, as well as the function in which I am working.

Header.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node {
  int data;
  int next;
};


void push(int*node_ptr, void*pie, size_t width );
```

Function.c:

```
void push(int *node_ptr, void *pie, size_t width) {

  struct Node *next, *prev, *head, *p;

  newmalloc(width); //Returns number of bytes
  

}
```

How do I actually go about allocating memory for the `struct Node structure` using the returned integer from `newmalloc`, without using malloc? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221897/custom-malloc-implementation, https://github.com/miguelperes/custom-malloc and other sites found by googling "C custom malloc"

Comment: The code posted doesn't make a lot of sense. But generally you can implement linked lists by using a static-sized array acting as memory pool and then using indices instead of `next` pointers. It's massively faster than traditional "heap fragmentation linked lists". Alternatively you can do caller allocation of the nodes.

Comment: You can implement your own malloc using sbrk and brk https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html

Comment: regarding: `newmalloc(width);`   Your commentary says this returns a byte count.  So why is there no local variable/pointer there to receive that byte count.  I.E.  `int * bytecount = newmalloc(width);`

Comment: OT: The posted header file is missing the needed 'guard' statements.  suggest: at the top:  `ifndef FUNCTION_H  #define FUNCTION_H`  and at the end: `#endif`